# Can a managed package be converted to unmanaged package?

Tags: apex, managed-package, unmanaged-package

Can a managed package be converted to unmanaged package by the vendor? If it is possible, how can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package components would need to be moved to a different org (easy to do if they are already under version control as they should be) and a new unmanaged package definition created there.

But note that the unmanaged package components would not have a namespace so it would be hard to change an existing installation that used the managed package into one that used the unmanaged package.

Comment: An interesting thing to notice is that a managed package can coexist with the same packaged, unmanaged. Don't ask me how or why, but this happened once. We found some funny bugs because of this in our project (because of namespace issues). :D

Comment: Thanks @RenatoOliveira. Cant the vendor make the same installed managed package unmanaged ?

Comment: Thanks @Keith C. We are discussing a possibility of what if our managed package vendor shuts goes out of business. What would be the ideal way to handle such case ? if provided we entirely work in their managed package.

Comment: @Jaguar What happens if they go out of business is indeed a good question to which I haven't seen a good answer.

Comment: @Jaguar as explained by Keith, the vendor would need to gather all the package's metadata and import it into your org, just like an org migration. Currently it is not possible to "convert" a managed installation to an unmanaged one.

Comment: Pretty sure a vendor can make a separate unmanaged version of their package in the same packaging org where the managed version exists - so the result would be similar to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/18269/renato-oliveira answer but you could just install as a unmanaged package. But you'd likely hit all sorts of namespace issues with fields being called the same thing minus the namespace, which can break dynamic SOQL etc, so you'd want to remove the managed version rather than have them co-exist

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Understood.. but before the vendor import all the metadata in my org wouldn't they need to uninstall the existing package which will result in loss of data ?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on what the app does, really. You can just "disable" the app, if it is a simple one (your app vendor should be able to tell if it is ok to have two versions installed). However, having two identical apps doesn't make sense. The proper way of doing this would be to export your data, uninstall the app, install the unpackaged version, and then import the original data to the freshly installed app.